# Исходник по работе с OpenAPI ВКонтакте

Tags: php, javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно достать бесплатный исходник по работе с `OpenAPI` ВКонтакте.

Answer (score 1):

http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php

Comment: А можно исходник примера, а то здесь нет. Мне, просто, легче изучать имея перед глазами пример.